# Gitlab & AWS parameter store

Tags: amazon-web-services, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, aws-parameter-store

We want to save all our AWS accounts credentials in AWS parameter store for better security.
now the question is:
How can we use the credentials stored in AWS parameter store in GitLab for deployment?

Comment: It depends on where you want to deploy EC2, ECS, you use docker, or just an artifact,...?

Comment: Some teams in the company use Docker and some use ECS.

Answer (score 0):

In your project, you can configure [.gitlab_ci.yaml](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/gitlab_ci_yaml.html) to make many things, one of them is to deploy your application, and there are many ways, one of them is to:

- Create a docker of your project
- Push the image to ECR
- Create a new ECS task definition with the new version of your docker image
- Create a new ECS service with the new version of the task definition

and to do so, you need effectively the credentials of AWS that you have configured in your GitLab repository.

After that their many ways to deploy from GitLab to AWS, it depends on your company and what tools you are using.